# MVC3 EF issues on multiple table

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

i am developing a database with 3 tables

Trip Model:

```
    [Key]
    public int TripId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Driver")]
    public int DriverId { get; set; }
    public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }

    public string StartingPoint { get; set; }

    public string Destination { get; set; }

    public DateTime TimeDepart { get; set; }

    public int SeatAvailable { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Driver> Drivers { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Passenger> Passengers { get; set; }
```

Driver model:

```
    [Key]
    public int DriverId { get; set; }

    public string DriverName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Trip"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public int TripId { get; set; }
    public virtual Trip Trip { get; set; }
```

And last passenger model:

```
    [Key]
    public int PassengerId { get; set; }

    public string PassengerName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Trip"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int TripId { get; set; }
    public virtual Trip Trip { get; set; }
```

With:

```
    public class LiveGreenContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Trip> Trips { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Driver> Drivers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Passenger> Passengers { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
    }
```

And i get the following error:

> Model compatibility cannot be checked because the EdmMetadata type was
>   not included in the model. Ensure that IncludeMetadataConvention has
>   been added to the DbModelBuilder conventions.

Any solutions on this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an initializer setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a call to the [Database.SetInitializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679461%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method in the `Application_Start` event handler of your `Global.asax`:

```
Database.SetInitializer<ContextName>(null);
```

where `ContextName` is the name of your custom [DbContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) class.